# Distance between dielectric union and nearest soldered joint

Tags: plumbing, soldering

A dielectric union comes with plastic gaskets that are vulnerable to melting near high heat. What is the minimum distance between it and a nearest soldered joint to avoid the heat from soldering compromising the gaskets?

[image]

Comment: Heat blocking putty is a thing that AC techs use to block heat from traveling down a pipe.  Works for plumbing too, but not used as much since the temp for soldering is lower than brazing.  [Example video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0nyzrRdC704)

Answer (score 2):

Dielectric fittings are not soldered in place. They are taken apart so the plastic insulator and rubber gasket are not ruined by the heat from soldering torch.

@ amphibient; the type of gas you use to solder copper tubing and fittings is of little importance. Propane has less heat than MAPP gas which has less heat than acetylene. I always preferred acetylene while a good friend preferred propane. For the DIY person, use what you have and use a medium temperature solder that is "lead free"such as 95/5 or similar and soldering paste on the tubing itself. After the solder cools, wipe the soldered joint with a damp cloth to remove the excess flux paste.

Comment: I have an elbow 5" away from the copper side of the union

Comment: I don't understand the DV either so I up voted it. If the fittings can be disassembled, definitely do it. Just remember to put the insulator back in place before soldering fittings on the other end of the pipe.

Comment: I assume a downvote was from the implication that OP planned to solder the fitting. That's not what was stated or asked. The question is about sweat joints _near_ the fitting.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a matter of distance, but of technique. Some tips:

- Disassemble the fitting and remove the vulnerable parts if possible.
- Regardless of the gas you use (which isn't really important), only apply enough heat to do the sweat. Prepare the scene so you can work
  quickly, then cool the pipes.
- Go old-school and wrap a wet rag around the pipe and fitting. It's very difficult to overheat a fitting with water against it.

Comment: If I have an elbow 5" away from the union, I can't remove the gaskets (there are two of them) before the sweating and put it back after because they won't go over the elbow.

Comment: @amphibient  But you can slide the nut and gaskets to the elbow, sweat and when cool, slide them back.  Use the wet & wrap.

Comment: you can do it only up to the first elbow. The gasket won't pass over an elbow but will over straight pipe